# When I start my Spring boot application it is not reading properties from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot jar file  on the server at path /data/myproj/myproj.jar

I have an application.yml at path /data/myproj

When I go to path /data/myproj and run java -jar myproj.jar, it is not reading the profile from application .yml

spring:
  profiles: qa-env

However, I add application.properties to path /data/myproj/

application.properties:  spring.profiles.active=qa-env

and run java -jar myproj.jar, it is reading the profile correctly.

Why would it not pick up the profile value from application.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below property is used to define the env specific configuration and not to mention which profile is active. 
spring:
  profiles:  "qa-env"

Make sure you are using below property in application.yml to activate "qa-env"

spring:
  profiles:
    active: "qa-env"

Indentation is really important in case of yml file.

Comment: Thank you. I was setting just the profile in application.yml instead of active profile.